# NAT with IPv6 (Forced by ISP)

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, nat

My ISP has recently decided that "high bandwidth clients" are now forced to use IPv6.  While I can plug my laptop with Win7 directly into the modem and I have access, connecting routers or my smoothwall firewall directly to the modem nets a failed connection.

Is there any type of linux setup that I could use to accept an IPv6 connection on eth0, and have that NAT out to devices on eth1?

I understand all of the benefits of using IPv6, but I have a ton of concerns.  For example, I have some legacy hardware that cannot communicate via IPv6.  I also don't want my ISP aware of the number of devices on my network.  Last thing I need is them jacking up my rates because my tv, pc, laptop, phone, etc. are all connected.  I also want to be able to VPN in like I currently do (well, used to at this point) and see all of my devices.

tl;dr: is there any simple or pre-packaged way to connect an IPv6 modem to a dual nic linux box and use that box as a ipv4 router for your local network? The OS doesn't matter so long as it works.

Reference links

[Will the removal of NAT (with the use of IPv6) be bad for consumers?](https://superuser.com/questions/407102/will-the-removal-of-nat-with-the-use-of-ipv6-be-bad-for-consumers)

[Without NAT on IPv6, and only one DNS name, how do i talk to my servers?](https://superuser.com/questions/319121/without-nat-on-ipv6-and-only-one-dns-name-how-do-i-talk-to-my-servers)

[IPv6 tunnel from behind an ISP-level NAT](https://superuser.com/questions/524293/ipv6-tunnel-from-behind-an-isp-level-nat)

---

The solution here is still a bit unknown.

- I tried a Netgear N600 (~$80 at Walmart).  It could not connect to the internet.
- I tried a Linksys AC1750 (~$190 at Staples).  Even with IPv6 right on the box, I couldn't get it to connect.
- I tried plugging straight in with Win7, internet works fine, but ICS, while I could set it up, wouldn't work as intended.
- Had the ISP bring out their router.  They plugged it in and BAM, working flawlessly.

Anyway, I don't have a real answer to this.  All I've got is "I can throw hardware at it, but until the ISP uses theirs, I'm SOL".

Comment: I'm guessing you're using carrier grade nat (what range is your ipv4 address in?), but what kind of IPv6 provision are they using? I'd guess the issue here might be with the router or smoothwall firewall not being set up for ipv6. You might also want to ask a second question about configuring your firewall for ipv6, and to add the information on the non functional routers here. I'd also give ICS from windows  a shot, just to see if a simple ipv4 routing setup would work. I have *some* ideas here but not enough for an answer.

Comment: I did some research yesterday and determined that smoothwall does not have IPv6 support.  Even the latest RC doesn't have it.  My normal router is a D-Link Gamer Lounge, and it doesn't seem to have support for IPv6 either, at least that I can determine.  My old ipv4 range was either (66.188.x.x) or (75.128.x.x).  How do I determine what type of provision they are using?

Comment: I don't have a windows server license.  That's why I'm looking for some hopefully free flavor of linux that can handle the job.

Comment: ICS works on windows 7. As for IPV6 provisioning, you'll need to know it to set up your router. I'm guessing here though what you need is an IPv6 capable router You *should* be able to get your current router on IPv4 though. Does your ISP use a modem or a modem router? I'd also check what the ip address is when you plug in your laptop, as well as when its just the router

Comment: I would agree with Journeyman.  There might be ways to avoid simply buying a new router, that supports IPv6, but at the end of the day the simplest solution and honestly likely the best one would be to purchase a new router.  Your service provider would be unware of any devices connected to this new router, just like they were unaware of the devices before the change.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another license of Windows 7. While connecting to the internet on my windows 7 laptop does work, I cannot use my laptop in such a way since it travels with me.  I do not have any other windows based devices.  Everything I've got aside from the laptop is either linux, android, or embedded.  If buying a new router is the only option I've got, would anyone happen to know of a good IPv6 router?  I've been reading reviews, and none of them sound that good.

Comment: As an update, I broke down and spent $180 on a Linksys AC1750 router that does have IPv6 support.  I've tried everything and can't get it to connect.  I can still plug my laptop in and get access though.  I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: Probably need to clone your MAC address. Anyway, your ISP should be supporting DHCPv6 and prefix delegation, so if you enable those you should get IPv6 throughout your network. If you don't, you need to yell at your ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have available hardware to use, consider installing [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) firewall. It has [support for IPv6](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Is_there_IPv6_support_available), various [VPN](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VPN_Capability_Overview) and a mile long list of [other features](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php@option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=43.html) equival to $50k-100k Cisco devices.
It has some learning curve, but if you are up for it you won't need anything else.